# How are PHP static variables implemented internally?

Tags: php, c, compiler-construction, static

I'd like for xdebug to someday be able to browse all static variables and properties, but according to the author there's no way to get a list of these in the engine. This is surprising to me because statics just seem like global vars with isolated scope.

Are they really not stored in a hash table, or is the problem that the table entries are just not enumerable?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're better off asking either Derick Rethans (author of XDebug and active developer of the PHP language / Zend Engine) or asking this at the php internals list (internals@lists.php.net)

Comment: Looking at them as global vars is a narrow view I think. You can have a static variable in a function, it only gets initialized once.  Otherwise it's just like any other variable.

Comment: @BrentBaisley Note that, besides statics allowing a shortcut initializer, they behave identically: http://3v4l.org/68uRA

Comment: Well this is even more surprising: http://3v4l.org/JTc71 "static" gives you an internal value, but you can just unbind it from the current scope, reuse the local var, and rebind it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A PHP function can internally be of two kinds: Either an internal function or a user-defined function. Internal functions are written in C and can do "anything". User-defined functions are represented by their "oparray" with meta data. The oparray contains the expressions of the function in PHP's/ZE's bytecode form. An element of the oparray contains a table of all static variables.

So in order to get all static variables one has to iterate over all user-defined functions (and class methods in all classes) and check that array.

For global functions this untested C code might do the trick:

```
int dump_statics(zend_function *function TSRMLS_DC)
{
    if (function->type == ZEND_USER_FUNCTION) {
        ulong    hashIndex    = 0;
        char*    hashKey      = NULL;
        int      hashKeyType  = 0;
        zend_hash_internal_pointer_reset(function->op_array.static_variables);
        while ((hashKeyType = zend_hash_get_current_key(function->op_array.static_variables, &hashKey, &hashIndex, 0)) {
            if (hashKeyType == HASH_KEY_IS_STRING) {
                php_printf("%s\n", hashkey);
            }
            zend_hash_move_forward(function->op_array.static_variables);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
zend_hash_apply(EG(function_table), (apply_func_t) dump_statics TSRMLS_CC);
```

For class methods one has to iterate over EG(class_table) and then the included funtion_table of the class entry ... that is left as an exercise to the reader. (as is testing the code above)

---

Update:

I've created a simple PHP extension doing that. It's available from https://github.com/johannes/php-staticvardumper

Comment: I assume you mean "So in order to get all static *variables* one has to iterate..."

Comment: So I assume `hashKey` references some kind of globally accessible table? And xdebug, to stay fast, would probably need all these hash keys in a big linked list? Just curious: are globals stored in the same table?

Comment: zend_hash_apply is an outer iterator acting on the function table. In there the zend_hash_* functions do an inner iteration on the static variable table. `hashKey` is a local variable which retrieves the key (-> variable name)

Comment: Oh, so `hashKey` is actually the variable name (without `$`)?